# Find Firmware Upgrade for Refurb Server

Tags: bios, firmware

I got a refurb deal on an HP Proliant ML110 G7 at Newegg.  Just what I needed for a home server.

I am hitting what seems to be a known limitation where if you fully populate the drive array AND add another drive via the on-mboard SATA port, you will not be able to boot from that last drive.

I found workarounds for this, maybe, but it seems everything depends on getting the BIOS upgraded.

HP's support page says you need an entitlement to download anything like a BIOS upgrade, and my server is no longer entitled because it's too old!

Anyone know another way to get this BIOS upgrade?  Not looking to bootleg it, willing to pay for properly licensed software.

Comment: How about asking Newegg?

Comment: They told me to go to HP support LOL